# How to generate QR code with my database details

Tags: php

How can I create a QR code with my database details for example in my database there is a table `myTable` and in it the columns are

- name
- place
- area
- phone

For these details how can I create.
Such that when I scan the code all the details has to be appear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I am not going to write the code for you, but I'll give you some pointers.

You could use a php library for creating qr codes like this one: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

And as you see in the examples you can create a qr code, using code like this:

```
QRcode::png('Your data inside here', 'filename.png');
```

Hope this helps you out so you can figure out how to write the neccessary code.